# Copiar apk localizado em /data/app/ programaticamente

Tags: java, android

**Olá**, eu gostaria de copiar um apk localizado na pasta **/data/app/**..
Mas o apk não está sendo copiado, apenas a pasta é criada, segue o código:

```
InputStream input;
            String apkPath = "/data/app/com.app.exemplo/base.apk";
            String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            try {
                File apk = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+apkPath);
                File directory = new File(sdPath + "/copiarAqui/");
                if (!directory.exists()){
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }
                input = new FileInputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                        + apkPath);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath() +
                        "apktest.apk");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int lenght;
                while ((lenght = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Copiado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

As permissões já estão em meu aplicativo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Alguém pode me dizer o problema?

Comment: Está a testar num emulador ou num dispositivo real? O conteúdo da pasta ***/data/*** só está disponível num emulador ou num "rooted device".

Comment: @ramaral Olá! Estou testando em um dispositivo real. Pensei que não fosse somente para rooted device, pois também é possível fazer backup de apps instalados sem root. Então pensei que a pasta /data/app/ seria possível fazer a leitura sem root. Será que tem alguma forma de fazer o backup pela package name? Somente de uma package name, sem listar todos os apps.